# Why does SPARQL query take 30x as long in R package than on Land Registry?

Tags: r, sparql

When I run the following SPARQL query on the [Land Registry](https://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole) console it takes c.0.4 seconds and returns all 2599 results:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
              
              SELECT
                ?stripped_regionName ?stripped_date ?ukhpi ?avprice ?volume ?newbuildvolume ?regionName ?regionId ?region 
              
              WHERE
              {
                VALUES ?regionId {<http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/southampton>   <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/london>  <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/england> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/wales>   <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/scotland>    <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/barking> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/southwark>   <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/westminster> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/merton> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/greenwich> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/camden>}
              
                    ?region ukhpi:refRegion  ?regionId .
                    ?region ukhpi:refMonth ?date .
                  ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndex ?ukhpi .
                    ?region ukhpi:averagePrice ?avprice .
                    ?region ukhpi:salesVolume ?volume .
                    ?region ukhpi:salesVolumeNewBuild ?newbuildvolume .
                
                  ?regionId rdfs:label ?regionName
                  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?regionName), "EN") ) .
                  BIND (STR(?regionName)  AS ?stripped_regionName) .
                  BIND (STR(?date)  AS ?stripped_date) .
              }
```

When I run the same query using the SPARQL package for R, it takes c.15.0 seconds to return all 2599 results:

```
  endpoint <- "https://landregistry.data.gov.uk/landregistry/query"
  query <- '
                  prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
                  prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
                  
              
              
              SELECT
                ?stripped_regionName ?stripped_date ?ukhpi ?avprice ?volume ?newbuildvolume ?regionName ?regionId ?region 
              
              WHERE
              {
                VALUES ?regionId {<http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/southampton>   <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/london>  <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/england> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/wales>   <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/scotland>    <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/barking> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/southwark>   <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/westminster> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/merton> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/greenwich> <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/camden>}
              
                    ?region ukhpi:refRegion  ?regionId .
                    ?region ukhpi:refMonth ?date .
                  ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndex ?ukhpi .
                    ?region ukhpi:averagePrice ?avprice .
                    ?region ukhpi:salesVolume ?volume .
                    ?region ukhpi:salesVolumeNewBuild ?newbuildvolume .
                
                  ?regionId rdfs:label ?regionName
                  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?regionName), "EN") ) .
                  BIND (STR(?regionName)  AS ?stripped_regionName) .
                  BIND (STR(?date)  AS ?stripped_date) .
              }'


  qd <- SPARQL(endpoint, query)
  hpi_df <- qd$results
```

Is there a way to speed up the query when run through R, or is the delay unavoidable? I'm hoping there is a fix, but imagine it could be because the Land Registry console is always connected, but my R query needs to connect to the server first.

Comment: Just as a data point: I ran your query connecting to the sparql endpoint using RDF4J in Java, and got a full result in < 1s , so I assume the problem you're seeing is specific to the R package implementation you're using.

Comment: Thanks for checking, that is helpful for narrowing the problem down. Interestingly I can't find much elsewhere on the SPARQL package for R being generally slow, but I'll double check to see whether there are any alternative packages that could do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this one, as far as I can see it does appear to be the R package that is slow.

My way around it was to download all the data and pre-load this, then create a function to only query and add new data each time someone loads up the app.

Filtering the data returned by the query to the minimum fields needed also helped.